# SQL Server Select Where value LIKE(temporary table value)

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-like

I have a function in SQL server 2008 that takes a string: 'A,B,C,D' and splits it and creates a table of the values.

```
Values
------
A
B
C
D
```

I now want to search a table (Users) Where a column value is LIKE one of the rows (surname) in the above table.

This is what I would like to do:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE vLastName LIKE 'A%'
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE vLastName LIKE 'B%'
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE vLastName LIKE 'C%'
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE vLastName LIKE 'D%'
```

If the above is not possible, how else would you do it? Some kind of loop?

I'm using SQL Server 2008

Comment: Why are you executing it 4 times? Why not simply use "OR"?

Comment: Sorry, should have made it clear, i'm passing in 'A,B,C,D'. So it needs to be dynamically split. Could be anything: 'E,F,G,H' etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Users,NewTable WHERE vLastName LIKE Values + '%'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * from Users u 
JOIN StringSplitterResult r on r.Values = SUBSTRING( u.vLastName, 1,1)
```